# iPhone background music player

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, background-music

Can anyone either direct me to a tutorial, or show me actual code to play background music. I need it to be able to start and stop. This is NOT an assignment so you know. My assignment is already done i just want to add music to it and I dont know how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use AVAudioPlayer

```
//You have to import AvFoundation to use AVAudioPlayer
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

-(void) playMusicFile:(NSString *) songName
{   
    NSString *musicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:songName ofType:@"mp3"];

    NSError *soundError = nil;
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicFile] error:&soundError];
    if(self.audioPlayer == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",soundError);
    }
    else
    {
        //Delegation is optional but it helps you do stuff after song finished playing etc
        [self.audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        //Set number of repeats, 0 is default plays once, negative values makes it play infinitely
        [self.audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:0];
        //Prepare to play is not always necessary, but otherwise it can take time to play
        [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [self.audioPlayer play];
    }
}

//This is the delegate called after the song finished playing, you can use it to play other songs, or do other stuff
-(void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    ...
}
```

Stopping and pausing:

```
//You can easily stop and pause using: 
[self.audioPlayer stop]; //Stop doesn't work as you would expect. It doesn't set the current time to 0 but only undoes the setup you had with the audioplayer.
[self.audioPlayer pause];

//It is possible to call [self.audioPlayer play] after each method and playback will continue from where it left off.
```

For more info visit the reference : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: awesome, thanks a bunch. I see you have the file type @"mp3" but where should I put the actual name of the song I have like @"background music"?

Comment: i have shared a function playMusicFile, if you want to play backgroundmusic.mp3 call it like : [self playMusicFile:@"backgroundmusic"] .

Answer (score 1):

`AVPlayer` and `AVAudioPlayer` should work.